# OpenMP block gives false results

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I would appreciate your point of view where I might did wrong using OpenMP.
I parallelized this code pretty strait forward - yet even with single thread (i.e., call omp_set_num_threads(1)) I get wrong results.

I have checked with Intel Inspector, and I do not have a race condition, yet the Inspector tool indicated as a warning that a thread might approach other thread stack (I have this warning in other code I have, and it runs well with OpenMP). I do not think this is the problem.

```
SUBROUTINE GR(NUMBER_D, RAD_D, RAD_CC, SPECT)

  use TERM,only: DENSITY, TEMPERATURE, VISCOSITY, WATER_DENSITY, & 
                 PRESSURE, D_HOR, D_VER, D_TEMP, QQQ, UMU
  use SATUR,only: FF, A1, A2, AAA, BBB, SAT
  use DELTA,only: DDM, DT
  use CONST,only: PI, G

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,INTENT(IN) :: NUMBER_D
  DOUBLE PRECISION,INTENT(IN) :: RAD_CC(NUMBER_D), SPECT(NUMBER_D)
  DOUBLE PRECISION,INTENT(INOUT) :: RAD_D(NUMBER_D)

  DOUBLE PRECISION :: R3, DR3, C2, C0, P, Q, RAD_CR, SAT_CR, C4, A, & 
                      C, D, CC, DD, CC2, DD2, RAD_ST, DRAA, DRA, DM, X1                    
  INTEGER :: I

  DDM = 0.0D0

  !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) & 
  !$OMP PRIVATE(I,R3,DR3,C2,C0,P,Q,SAT,SAT_CR,C4,A) &
  !$OMP PRIVATE (C,D,CC,DD,CC2,DD2,RAD_ST,DRAA,DRA,DM,RAD_CR,X1) &
  !$OMP REDUCTION (+:DDM)
  DO I=1,NUMBER_D
     R3   = RAD_CC(I)**3
     DR3  = RAD_D(I)**3-R3
     IF(DR3.LT.1.0D-100) DR3 = 1.0D-100

     C2 = -DSQRT(3.0D0*BBB*R3/AAA)
     C0 = -R3
     P  = -0.3333333333D0*C2**2
     Q  = C0+0.074074074D0*C2**3
     CALL CUBIC(P, Q, RAD_CR)
     RAD_CR = RAD_CR - 0.3333333333D0*C2
     SAT_CR = DEXP(AAA/RAD_CR-BBB*R3/(RAD_CR**3-R3))-1.0D0

     DRA  = DT*(SAT+1.0D0-DEXP(AAA/RAD_DROP(I)-BBB*R3/DR3))/ &
           (FF*RAD_D(I))

     IF(SAT.LT.SAT_CR) THEN

        IF(DABS(SAT).LT.1.0D-10) THEN
           P = -BBB*R3/AAA
           Q = -R3
           CALL CUBIC(P, Q, RAD_ST)
           GO TO 22
        END IF


        C4  = DLOG(SAT+1.0D0)
        A   = -AAA/C4
        C   = (BBB-C4)*R3/C4
        D   = -A*R3
        P   = A*C-4.0D0*D
        Q   = -(A**2*D+C**2)

        CALL CUBIC(P, Q, X1)

        CC  = DSQRT(A**2+4.D0*X1)
        DD  = DSQRT(X1**2-4.D0*D)
        CC2 = 0.5D0*(A-CC)
        IF(SAT.LT.0.0D0) THEN
           DD2    = 0.5D0*(X1-DD)
           RAD_ST = 0.5D0*(-CC2+DSQRT(CC2**2-4.0D0*DD2))
        ELSE
           DD2    = 0.5D0*(X1+DD)
           RAD_ST = 0.5D0*(-CC2-DSQRT(CC2**2-4.0D0*DD2))
        END IF

22       CONTINUE

        DRAA = RAD_ST-RAD_D(I)
        IF(ABS(DRAA).LT.ABS(DRA)) THEN
           DRA = DRAA
           DM  = 1.3333333333333333D0*PI*WATER_DENSITY* &
                (RAD_ST**3-RAD_D(I)**3)
        ELSE
           DM  = 4.0D0*PI*WATER_DENSITY*RAD_D(I)**2*DRA
        END IF
        DDM = DDM+SPECT(I)*DM
        RAD_D(I) = RAD_D(I) + DRA
     ELSE
        DM  = 4.0D0*PI*WATER_DENSITY*RAD_D(I)**2*DRA
        DDM = DDM+SPECT(I)*DM
        RAD_D(I) = RAD_D(I) + DRA
     END IF

  END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

  RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE GR

SUBROUTINE CUBIC(P, Q, X)

  IMPLICIT NONE

  DOUBLE PRECISION,INTENT(IN) :: P, Q
  DOUBLE PRECISION,INTENT(OUT) :: X

  DOUBLE PRECISION :: DIS, PP, COSALFA,ALFA, QQ, U, V 

  DIS = (P/3.D0)**3+(0.5D0*Q)**2
  IF(DIS.LT.0.0D0) THEN
     PP      = -P/3.0D0
     COSALFA = -0.5D0*Q/DSQRT(PP**3)
     ALFA    = DACOS(COSALFA)
     X       = 2.0D0*DSQRT(PP)*DCOS(ALFA/3.0D0)
     RETURN
  ELSE
     QQ  = DSQRT(DIS)
     U   = -0.5D0*Q+QQ
     V   = -0.5D0*Q-QQ
     IF(U.GE.0.0D0) THEN
        U = U**0.333333333333333D0
     ELSE
        U = -(-U)**0.333333333333333D0
     END IF
     IF(V.GE.0.0D0) THEN
        V = V**0.333333333333333D0
     ELSE
        V = -(-V)**0.333333333333333D0
     END IF
     X = U+V
  END IF

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE CUBIC
```

Comment: Where is `CUBIC`? What it does? A compilable and runnable example would be nice. I suggest you to use `log` and `sqrt` instead of `DLOG` and `DSQRT` and operators `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=` for readability.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the note. 'CUBIC' is a subroutine which gets two real numbers ('P','Q') and returns the third one.

Comment: OK, construct a fully compilable example and supply the desired behavior with it and the actual behavior you don't understand.

Comment: Like "implicit none" in a Fortran source file, you should use DEFAULT(none) in OpenMP constructs. This will help you to find trouble induced by wrong shared/private settings

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark well, running it with/without OpenMP gives different numbers, especially the 'DDM' accumulative parameter. I excluded data race condition by compiling with '-openmp' but with 1 thread.

Comment: I have tried to define even further the arguments/array as :
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE) & 
  !$OMP PRIVATE(I,R3,DR3,C2,C0,P,Q,SAT,SAT_CR,C4,A) &
  !$OMP PRIVATE (C,D,CC,DD,CC2,DD2,RAD_ST,DRAA,DRA,DM,RAD_CR,X1) &
  !$OMP REDUCTION (+:DDM) SHARED(NUMBER_DROP, RAD_CCN, BBB, AAA, DT) & 
  !$OMP SHARED (FF, PI, WATER_DENSITY, SPECT) FIRSTPRIVATE(RAD_DROP)

But still, I'm getting results as if one of the variable is set (automatically?) to zero or some other default value.

@HighPerformanceMark I do not see any point talking about initialization dependent numbers, but over the logic of code.

Comment: Problem solved. By careful inspection, the variable 'SAT' is initialized to zero automatically if declared to be 'PRIVATE'. It should be 'SHARED'. Thanks to all.